# Get a layout's widgets in PyQT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a `QVBoxLayout` that I've added a few widgets to, via `addWidget()`.  I need to now delete those widgets, and it seems I need to use `removeWidget()` (which takes in a widget to be removed) to do that.

I thought that calling `children()` or `findChildren(QWidget)` on my layout would return a list of the widgets I've added into it; I'm in the debugger, though, and am just receiving empty lists.

Am I terribly misunderstanding something?  I've just started doing PyQT this last week and have mostly been learning through trial and error with the API docs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's odd. My understanding is that adding widgets via `addWidget` transfers ownership to the layout so calling `children()` ought to work.

However, as an alternative you could loop over the layout items by using `count()` and `itemAt(int)` to supply a `QLayoutItem` to `removeItem(QLayoutItem*)`.

**Edit:**

I've just tried `addWidget` with a straight C++ test app. and it doesn't transfer `QObject` ownership to the layout so `children()` is indeed an empty list. The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#addItem) clearly say that ownership is transferred though...

**Edit 2:**

Okay, it looks as though it transfers ownership to the widget that has that layout (which is *not* what the docs said). That makes the items in the layout siblings of the layout itself in the `QObject` hierarchy! It's therefore easier to stick with `count` and `itemAt`.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thank you.  It doesn't work quite as I'd like it, but that appears to be due to some display updating issues I need to iron out, which are quite independent of this.

Comment: Oh, so `itemAt` gives out a QWidgetItem (which necessitates the usage of `removeItem`, which for whatever reason wasn't doing what I wanted).  If you call `.widget()` on it, though, you'll get (shock!) the QWidget associated with it, which can be removed with `removeWidget` and set to have a parent of `None`.

Answer (score 30):

To get a widget from a QLayout, you have to call its `itemAt(index)` method. 
As the name of this method implies, it will return an item instead of a widget. Calling `widget()` on the result will finally give you the widget:

```
myWidget = self.myLayout.itemAt(index).widget()
```

To remove a widget, set the parent widget to `None`:

```
myWidget.setParent(None)
```

Also really helpfull is the QLayout `count()` method. To find and delete all contents of a layout:

```
index = myLayout.count()
while(index >= 0):
    myWidget = myLayout.itemAt(index).widget()
    myWidget.setParent(None)
    index -=1
```

Comment: `index = myLayout.count()-1` I agree with this answer but the -1 should be there at the top as index starts from 0 and if you dont do that the index goes till -1 in the loop.