# Looping over widgets inside widgets inside layouts

Tags: python, loops, layout, pyqt, qgroupbox

Similar question to what we have here [Loop over widgets in PyQt Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150182/loop-over-widgets-in-pyqt-layout) but a bit more complex...

I have

```
QVGridLayout
   QGroupBox
      QGridLayout
         QLineEdit
```

I'd like to access QLineEdit but so far I dont know how to access children of QGroupBox

```
        for i in range(self.GridLayout.count()):
            item = self.GridLayout.itemAt(i)
            for i in range(item.count()):
                lay = item.itemAt(i)
                edit = lay.findChildren(QLineEdit)
                print edit.text()
```

Can any1 point me to right dirrection?

Answer (score 11):

When a widget is added to a layout, it automatically becomes a child of the widget the layout it is set on. So the example reduces to a two-liner:

```
for group in self.GridLayout.parentWidget().findChildren(QGroupBox):
    for edit in group.findChildren(QLineEdit):
        # do stuff with edit
```

However, `findChildren` is *recursive*, so if all the line-edits are in group-boxes, this can be simplified to a one-liner:

```
for edit in self.GridLayout.parentWidget().findChildren(QLineEdit):
    # do stuff with edit
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorted :

```
for i in range(self.GridLayout.count()):
     item = self.GridLayout.itemAt(i)
     if type(item.widget()) == QGroupBox:
          child =  item.widget().children()
```

I had to use item.widget() to get access to GroupBox. 
Hope this helps some1.

Comment: what is gridlayout