# How to get list of widgets in pyqt?

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

I am designing a interface with QtDesigner and editing its functionalities with PyQt. One of the widgets that i created has several pushButtons and i want them all to have the property Checkable = True.

So currently what i am doing is:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('./my_widget.ui', self)
        self.pushButton_X.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_Y.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_Z.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton_ETC.setCheckable(True)
        self.show()
```

Is there any way i can do something like:

```
pushbuttons_list = self.get_all_pushbuttons()
for i in pushbuttons_list:
    i.setCheckable(True)
```

?

Im trying the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150182/loop-over-widgets-in-pyqt-layout) but i keep getting

```
>  File "./testing_class.py", line 12, in __init__
    items = (self.layout.itemAt(i) for i in range(self.layout.count())) 
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example failed because all [Qt properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) can be accessed by *calling* the attribute (see the parentheses used for `self.layout()`):

```py
items = (self.layout().itemAt(i) for i in range(self.layout().count()))
```

Note that this will only get access to the *layout items*, not the widgets they might (or might not) contain. For this, using comprehensions will only complicate things unnecessarily, as one-liners should be used only as long as they keep the code readable; the comprehension above is already complex enough, and since you will need to cycle through all items anyway, there's little use in it. Just use a for loop, which is far more readable:

```
for i in range(self.layout().count()):
    widget = self.layout().itemAt(i).widget()
    if isinstance(widget, QPushButton):
        widget.setCheckable(True)
```

Note that if you have several buttons that you want checkable and you are doing this only to avoid manually setting the checkable property for all of them, you can just use the extended selection mode that is common for all UI elements that allow selection by keeping pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when clicking multiple objects.
The property editor will automatically show all common properties for the selected widgets, and apply the changed property to all of them.

---

Another option is to use [`findChildren()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren):

```
for button in self.findChildren(QPushButton, Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly):
    button.setCheckable(True)
```

The `Qt.FindDirectChildrenOnly` flag is required whenever you have complex layouts that have nested widgets containing other buttons, if you remove that you will find *any* push button that exists inside the window (or the widget referenced as `self`).

---

Finally, buttons can be part of a [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html), which can also be created in Designer. Just select all buttons (as explained above), right click on one of them and select "Assign to button group", and then:

```
for button in self.buttonGroup.buttons():
    button.setCheckable(True)
```

Note that the `self.buttonGroup` above is the object name assigned by Designer, if you change it or you create more than one, ensure that the reference matches it.

Comment: Your answer definitely helps: the buttonGroup works and so does the findchildren method. However, i tried putting your first version of the code in the __init__ function of the widget class and substituting the "widget.setCheckable(True)" by "print(widget.objectName())". I get no errors when initializing the widget but also get no prints. Am i doing something wrong? (i will edit the question to add the code)

Comment: Please don't edit the question with portions of an answer, as it makes the question very confusing. If it doesn't print anything, it means that those buttons are part of a nested layout, so you can only use `findChildren()` in that case, unless you have the reference for that *specific* layout. If the buttons are inside a frame named `self.frame`, you should use `self.frame.layout()` for both `count()` and `itemAt()`, but remember that this might still not work if the layout contains other layouts inside of it.

Comment: Using frame.layout() worked!